# Timer how to fix

Tags: javascript, timer

I was just wondering with this, how can I get it to display only seconds when minutes hit zero?
So instead of displaying "0 minutes and 41 seconds"
I would like it to only display "41 seconds"
Is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = <? = $time['timefromdb'] ?>;
    var now = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    count = count - now;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will* run it every 1 second 
    function timer() {
        count = count - 1;
        if (count == -1) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
        }
        var seconds = count % 60;
        var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
        var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
        minutes %= 60;
        hours %= 24;
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: don't add the `minutes + " minutes and "` to the output if minutes is 0

Comment: I would but the time on this may be 25 minutes, it may be 25 seconds, depends on the user, what I want is for it not to display0 minutes when minutes are below zero? If that makes sense

Comment: yes, and I explained how you would do it

Comment: But the way you explained it, it would only ever display the seconds and not the minutes.

Comment: `"if minutes is 0"` seems conditional to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = <?= $time['timefromdb'] ?>; 
    var now = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000); 
    count = count - now; 
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will* run it every 1 second 
    function timer()
     { 
     count = count - 1; 
     if(count == -1) 
     { 
     clearInterval(counter);
      return; 
      }
       var seconds = count % 60; 
       var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60); 
       var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60); 
       var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);   
       minutes %= 60; 
       hours %= 24;
       if (minutes > 0) {
          min = minutes + " minutes and ";
       }
       else {
          min = "";
       }
       document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML =  min  + seconds + " seconds";
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly, now to do this with all my timers, the ones that display hours and days..

Answer (score 2):

Simplest would be

```
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = (minutes?minutes+ " minutes and ":"")+ seconds + " seconds";
```